# Quotient of normal ring by principal ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, principal-ideal-domains

Let $A$ be a PID, $A ⊂ R ⊂ A[x_1,x_2]$ with $R$ normal. Suppose that $x ∈ A$ and $R/xR$ is a domain. Is $R/xR$ normal?
If not is there any condition on $R$ that will make this true?

Thank you.